# How do I output one audio source to 2 different USB speakers at the same time?

Tags: audio, speakers

USB speakers are running off different USB ports. I found something called Voicemeeter but I have to control the sound from within the program and I have to initialize it every time I turn on the computer. There is also a slight lag between the 2 audio outputs.

Preferably, I would like something that has zero lag and can allow me to adjust the volume straight from the taskbar.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it is impossible to achieve zero lag between two or more outputs in a non-professional audio system. Each audio device has its own internal clock used to convert digital samples to sound amplitudes in regular interval. Each hardware clock, even stabilized by a quartz crystal, has its own static frequency inaccuracy and dynamic fluctuations. If two independent clocks have been started at the exactly same time, they will diverge sooner or later. Most USB audio devices have no precise internal clocks, so they can diverge in minutes. To keep the clocks in sync, audio devices must have special synchronization features available in Pro Audio hardware only.

Additionally, wide-purpose systems like Windows don't support audio device synchronization natively.

You can try tools like [Virtual Audio Cable](https://vac.muzychenko.net), playing the sound to a virtual line (for example, Line 1), and repeating other line's end to both USB speakers, using Windows built-in Listen feature or Audio Repeater helper application. Such setup is not very easy but some users reported that it works acceptably, especially with KS version of Audio Repeater.